# Videos and Page scrolling are slow on my computer

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, gpu

I am having a problem in my brother's computer-
scrolling in pages (no matter what app), and watching youtube videos, and other streaming videos are working slow (playing videos in vlc from my computer works just fine)..

I tried 2 things:

1. I thought it might be a problem with the GPU driver - so I reinstalled it, nothing changed.
2. I used Ubuntu Live CD (without installing) to play videos and scroll through pages in order to check whether the GPU is defected - using Ubuntu Live everything works great (I chose Ubuntu because all drivers are pre-installed)

What should I do next to find and solve this problem?

Comment: As a troublshooting step, I suggest trying other browsers (ie, Firefox, Chrome, IE). Let us know if you still have problems with other browsers.

Comment: Also, what graphics card do you have? `lspci | grep VGA` out to reveal this if you don't know.